# How to `table` all factors columns and ggplot geom_bar with facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(
    cola = c('1',NA,'c','1','1','e','1',NA,'c','d'),
    colb = c("a",NA,"c","d",'a','b','c','d','c','d'),
    colc = c('a',NA,'1','d','a',NA,'c',NA,'c','d'),stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

table(df$cola)
```

Output of above R script is:

```
1 c d e 
4 2 1 1
```

We can use `geom_bar(stat = "identity"...,` in `ggplot` to plot bar like:
 [image]

How to use ggplot geom_bar with `facet_wrap` to one-time plot `cola`,`colb`,`colc` as below?
[image]

Comment: This plot is not produced by `ggplot2`. What kind of plot do you want to make and how is it related to `table`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: Reshape to long and plot. I would recommend going through the `ggplot2` vignette.

Comment: try `df %>% gather(na.rm = TRUE) %>% count(key, value) %>% ggplot(., aes(x = value, y = n)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~ key)`

Comment: @NelsonGon,I think `df` is already `long` format

Comment: @kittygirl It's wide. `ggplot2` works better with long data for some reason(s) that have been discussed by the devs in some old post I can't find right  now.

Comment: That's different question.I need to plot `table(column)`,not directly plot column.

Comment: @akrun,your comment is workable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We `gather` the columns to 'long' format and then do the `ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>%
     # gather to long format
     gather(na.rm = TRUE) %>%
     # get the frequency count of key, value columns
     count(key, value) %>% 
     ggplot(., aes(x = value, y = n)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
       # facet wrap with key column
       facet_wrap(~ key)
```

Comment: My teacher told me try to avoid using `%>%`,is there a way to use `melt` instead of `%>%` ?

Comment: What justification he gave you when he told you that?

Comment: @kittygirl  Yes you can use `library(reshape2)` (but `reshape2` is getting deprecated).  `df1 <- melt(df)` and use that in `ggplot2`

Comment: @kittygirl  I would also like to know the reason behind not using `%>%`.  Is it because of lots of dependency packages?

Comment: Besides package dependency,I remember some points:1.incompatible with markdown  2.not easy to read

Comment: @kittygirl  I think the whole selling point around tidyverse is `readability`.  Good to know that somebody disagress

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
  library(tidyverse)

  df %>%
  map(function(x){as.data.frame(table(x))}) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "variable") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = Freq)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

Comment: `Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector`,when I run your answer.But output is what I want.

Comment: A warning message is not a problem some times. Anyway, @akrun answer is more elegant than mine.

Comment: I think you can first convert to character then reconvert to factor after the manipulation.